# drag canvas con dos canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

estoy haciendo que uno puede subir el logo y posicionarla en cualquier parte de la imagen de fondo, el problema es que el drag me funciona con un canvas pero con dos aveces deja funcionar depues de un rato, saben si hay una forma de hacerlo diferente?. Lo que quiero es obtener la poscicion X, Y, ancho y alto del logo, el fondo se proporciona el ancho y el alto para poder visualizarlo

en este link es donde lo que llevo: https://jsfiddle.net/albert925/qt86spam/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día Albert, 
habrás notado que se deja de mover SOLO si haces scroll,
el problema está en la forma en la que agarras las coordenadas sin considerar el scroll

Lo que hice fue cambiar todos los clientX y clientY por pageX y pageY,
te dejo el JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bardackx/da645awk/